# Notepad ++ Insert New Line Before 'else if'

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to insert a new line before every instance of the phrase 'else if'. I know how to do this for a single word using

```
Find: else
Replace: \r
```

But I can't figure out how to search for a multi word string in the Find.

Apologies if these is really obvious; I've had a good hunt around regular expressions guides for Notepad ++ but I haven't been able to get anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Find: else if
Replace: \r\nelse if

Search Mode: Extended
```

Comment: Hi All

Thanks for the help - all great solutions. I've just figured out my source (Impromptu 7.4 expression editor) for the text was inserting two spaces... Sorry for using up your time!

Thanks

J

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

Find what: `(\belse if\b)`
Replace with: `\n$1`

Comment: Thanks - I get the error 'Can't find the text '(\belse if\b)' '. I've selected regular expression in the search mode. Are there other settings I need to change?

Comment: @james.mullan: You must check the checkbox "Regular Expression".

Comment: @james.mullan Make sure that your cursor is at the beginning of the file. Regex find/replace defaults to find/replace downwards only and won't find any match if your cursor is at the end.